# Laravel Backpack Inline Create not showing button to insert NEW ITEMS

Tags: laravel-backpack

I can't get the ADD NEW ITEM Button to that opens the modal with Inline create

But, strangely, in the primary class, I see the items that are related, inside a box, showed as buttons with an [x] to delete them.

Primary Class (FairCrudController.php)

```php
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use App\Http\Requests\FairRequest;
use Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\CrudController;
use Backpack\CRUD\app\Library\CrudPanel\CrudPanelFacade as CRUD;

/**
 * Class FairCrudController
 * @package App\Http\Controllers\Admin
 * @property-read \Backpack\CRUD\app\Library\CrudPanel\CrudPanel $crud
 */
class FairCrudController extends CrudController
{
    use \Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\Operations\ListOperation;
    use \Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\Operations\CreateOperation;
    use \Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\Operations\InlineCreateOperation;
    use \Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\Operations\UpdateOperation;
    use \Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\Operations\DeleteOperation;
    use \Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\Operations\ShowOperation;

    use \Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\Operations\FetchOperation;

    use \Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\Operations\BulkDeleteOperation;

    use \Backpack\EditableColumns\Http\Controllers\Operations\MinorUpdateOperation;

    /**
     * Configure the CrudPanel object. Apply settings to all operations.
     * 
     * @return void
     */
    public function setup()
    {
        CRUD::setModel(\App\Models\Fair::class);
        CRUD::setRoute(config('backpack.base.route_prefix') . '/fair');
        CRUD::setEntityNameStrings('feria', 'Ferias');
    }

    /**
     * Define what happens when the List operation is loaded.
     * 
     * @see  https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/crud-operation-list-entries
     * @return void
     */
    protected function setupListOperation()
    {
        CRUD::addColumn([
            'name'             => 'name',
            'type'             => 'editable_text',
            'label'            => 'Nombre',
            'underlined'       => true,
            'min_width'        => '120px',
            'select_on_click'  => false,
            'save_on_focusout' => false,
            'auto_update_row' => true,
          ]);

        CRUD::column('hero_image')->label('Imagen')->type('image');
        CRUD::column('start_at')->label('Empieza');
        CRUD::column('end_at')->label('Termina');
        CRUD::column('date_limit')->label('Límite');
        CRUD::addColumn([
          'name'  => 'status',
          'label' => 'Activada',
          'type'  => 'editable_switch',
          'color'   => 'success',
          'onLabel' => '✓',
          'offLabel' => '✕',
        ]);

        $this->crud->enableBulkActions();
        $this->crud->setDefaultPageLength(100);
        
        $this->crud->orderBy('start_at', 'DESC');
    }

    /**
     * Define what happens when the Create operation is loaded.
     * 
     * @see https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/crud-operation-create
     * @return void
     */
    protected function setupCreateOperation()
    {
        CRUD::setValidation(FairRequest::class);

        CRUD::field('name')->label('Nombre');
        CRUD::field('website')->label('Sitio Web');
        CRUD::field('invoice_prefix')->label('Prefijo de Facturas');
        CRUD::field('address')->label('Dirección');
        CRUD::field('city')->label('Ciudad');
        CRUD::field('state')->label('Estado/Provincia');
        CRUD::field('zip_code')->label('Código Postal');
        CRUD::field('country')->label('Pais');
        CRUD::field('contactperson')->type('relationship')->label('Personas de Contacto');
        CRUD::field('contact_persons_copy')->label('Poner en copia de los emails (separados por punto y coma)');
        CRUD::field('start_at')->label('Comienza');
        CRUD::field('end_at')->label('Termina');
        CRUD::field('date_limit')->label('Límite');
        $this->crud->addField([
            'label' => "Imagen de Presentación",
            'name' => "hero_image",
            'type' => 'image',
            'crop' => true,
            'aspect_ratio' => 0,
        ]);
        $this->crud->addField([
            'type' => "relationship",
            'name' => 'images',
            'label' => 'Imágenes',
            'ajax' => true,
            'inline_create' => true,
        ]);
        $this->crud->addField([
            'type' => "relationship",
            'name' => 'dossiers',
            'ajax' => true,
            'inline_create' => [ 'entity' => 'dossier' ],
            'data_source' => backpack_url('fair/fetch/dossier')
        ]);
        $this->crud->addField([
            'type' => "relationship",
            'name' => 'newsletters',
            'ajax' => true,
            'inline_create' => true,
        ]);
        CRUD::field('stands')->type('relationship')->label('Stands');
        CRUD::field('status')->label('Activa')->default(1);
    }

    /**
     * Define what happens when the Update operation is loaded.
     * 
     * @see https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/crud-operation-update
     * @return void
     */
    protected function setupUpdateOperation()
    {
        $this->setupCreateOperation();
    }

    /**
     * Define what happens when the View operation is loaded.
     * 
     * @see https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/5.x/crud-operation-show
     * @return void
     */
    protected function setupShowOperation()
    {
        CRUD::column('name')->label('Nombre');
        CRUD::column('website')->label('Sitio Web');
        CRUD::column('invoice_prefix')->label('Prefijo de Facturas');
        CRUD::column('address')->label('Dirección');
        CRUD::column('city')->label('Ciudad');
        CRUD::column('state')->label('Estado/Provincia');
        CRUD::column('zip_code')->label('Código Postal');
        CRUD::column('country')->label('Pais');
        CRUD::column('contact_persons_copy')->label('Poner en copia de los emails (separados por punto y coma)');
        CRUD::column('start_at')->label('Comienza');
        CRUD::column('end_at')->label('Termina');
        CRUD::column('date_limit')->label('Límite');

        CRUD::column('hero_image')->label('Imagen')->type('image');

        CRUD::column('status')->label('Activada')->type('check');
    }

    public function setupInlineCreateOperation() {
        $this->setupCreateOperation();
    }

    protected function fetchDossier()
    {
        return $this->fetch(\App\Models\Dossier::class);
    }
}
```

Secondary Class (DossierCrudController.php)

```php
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use App\Http\Requests\DossierRequest;
use Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\CrudController;
use Backpack\CRUD\app\Library\CrudPanel\CrudPanelFacade as CRUD;

/**
 * Class DossierCrudController
 * @package App\Http\Controllers\Admin
 * @property-read \Backpack\CRUD\app\Library\CrudPanel\CrudPanel $crud
 */
class DossierCrudController extends CrudController
{
    use \Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\Operations\ListOperation;
    use \Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\Operations\CreateOperation;
    use \Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\Operations\InlineCreateOperation;
    use \Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\Operations\UpdateOperation;
    use \Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\Operations\DeleteOperation;
    use \Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\Operations\ShowOperation;

    use \Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\Operations\BulkDeleteOperation;

    use \Backpack\EditableColumns\Http\Controllers\Operations\MinorUpdateOperation;


    /**
     * Configure the CrudPanel object. Apply settings to all operations.
     * 
     * @return void
     */
    public function setup()
    {
        CRUD::setModel(\App\Models\Dossier::class);
        CRUD::setRoute(config('backpack.base.route_prefix') . '/dossier');
        CRUD::setEntityNameStrings('dossier de la feria', 'dossiers de la feria');
    }

    /**
     * Define what happens when the List operation is loaded.
     * 
     * @see  https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/crud-operation-list-entries
     * @return void
     */
    protected function setupListOperation()
    {
        CRUD::addColumn([
            'name'    => 'fair_id',
            'label'   => 'Feria',
            'type'    => 'editable_select',
            'options' => \App\Models\Fair::all()->pluck('name', 'id')->toArray(),
            'underlined'       => true,
            'save_on_focusout' => true,
            'save_on_change'   => true,
            'auto_update_row' => true,
          ]);

        CRUD::addColumn([
            'name'             => 'name',
            'type'             => 'editable_text',
            'label'            => 'Nombre',
            'underlined'       => true,
            'min_width'        => '120px',
            'select_on_click'  => false,
            'save_on_focusout' => false,
            'auto_update_row' => true,
          ]);
          CRUD::addColumn([
            'name'  => 'status',
            'label' => 'Activado',
            'type'  => 'editable_switch',
            'color'   => 'success',
            'onLabel' => '✓',
            'offLabel' => '✕',
          ]);

          $this->crud->enableBulkActions();
          $this->crud->setDefaultPageLength(100);
          
          $this->crud->orderBy('fair_id', 'ASC');
    }

    /**
     * Define what happens when the Create operation is loaded.
     * 
     * @see https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/crud-operation-create
     * @return void
     */
    protected function setupCreateOperation()
    {
        CRUD::setValidation(DossierRequest::class);

        CRUD::field('fair')->type('select')->label('Feria');
        CRUD::field('name')->label('Nombre');
        CRUD::field('status')->label('Activo')->default(1);
        $this->crud->addField([
            'label' => "Archivo (Tamaño: 16MB máx.)",
            'name' => "file",
            'upload' => true,
            'type' => 'upload',
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Define what happens when the Update operation is loaded.
     * 
     * @see https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/crud-operation-update
     * @return void
     */
    protected function setupUpdateOperation()
    {
        $this->setupCreateOperation();
    }

    protected function setupShowOperation()
    {
        CRUD::column('fair')->label('Feria');
        CRUD::column('name')->label('Nombre');
        CRUD::column('file')->label('Archivo')->type('file');
        CRUD::column('status')->label('Activado')->type('check');
    }

    public function setupInlineCreateOperation() {
        $this->setupCreateOperation();
    }

}
```

/routes/backpack/custom.php

```php
....
Route::get('fair/fetch/dossier', [DossierCrudController::class, "fetchDossier"]);
....
```

Fair.php Model

```php
use App\Models\Dossier;
...
    public function dossiers()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Dossier::class);
    }
....
```

Dossier.php Model

```php
use App\Models\Fair;
...
    public function fair()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Fair::class);
    }
....
```

Comment: Hey Antop, I think you are missing two things: 
- adding `InlineCreateOperation` in both CrudControllers.
- defining the `fetch` route or the manually defining `data_source` for the field to properly work.

Comment: Thanks, @PedroX ! for your comments and help. I've modified the Code, as you see upside... But still doesn't work. What am I missing out?

Comment: Hey Antop, one thing that I see that you are doing wrong is defining the `public fetchSomething` and also defining the `Route::get`. The `FetchOperation` should register the url automatically. Have a look at: https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/5.x/crud-operation-fetch#about-1